# Assigning Specific Colors to Specific Wedges in Bokeh Pie Charts

Tags: python, bokeh

I am attempting to make pie charts out of a nested dictionary of poll questions and answers using Python and Bokeh.

```
questions = [ 'Question 1', 'Question 2', 'Question 3' ]

answers = { 0 : { 'Strongly Agree': 3, 'Agree': 3, 'Disagree': 2, 'Strongly Disagree': 1, 'Neutral': 1},
            1 : { 'Agree': 5, 'Strongly Disagree': 2, 'Neutral': 2, 'Disagree': 1 },
            2 : { 'Agree': 3, 'Strongly Disagree': 3, 'Disagree': 2, 'Neutral': 2 } }

def makePieChart(question,dataInput):
    data = pd.Series(dataInput).reset_index(name="value").rename(columns={'index':'rank'})
    data['color'] = ('blue',    # Strongly Agree
                     'green',   # Agree
                     'yellow',  # Neutral
                     'orange',  # Disagree
                     'red')     # Strongly Disagree

    data['angle'] = data['value']/data['value'].sum() * 2*pi

    p = figure(plot_height=350, title="Pie Chart", toolbar_location=None,
           tools="hover", tooltips="@country: @value")

    p.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.4, 
        
        # use cumsum to cumulatively sum the values for start and end angles
            start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
            line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend_field='rank', source=data)

    p.axis.axis_label=None
    p.axis.visible=False
    p.grid.grid_line_color = None

    show(p)
```

(Pardon any typos; I'm hand jamming it since I can't copy/paste at the moment.)

I want the responses to be in a specific order—`[ 'Strongly Agree', 'Agree', 'Neutral', 'Disagree', 'Strongly Disagree' ]`—and each of those answers to have the same color across all pie charts, even if some of the questions are lacking votes for all five options. How do I do this?